# Is it possible to change the CanWrite property in a FileStreamResult's FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream, filestreamresult

I want to try this in order to discard a possibility of why my code is not working as expected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot [prove a negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophic_burden_of_proof#Proving_a_negative).

Comment: What's that even supposed to mean...?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass steam that has `CanWrite` set the way you want in constructor. [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1167fw72(v=vs.110).aspx) is an option as it allows both R/O and R/W modes.

I.e. if you just need some result use following (indeed you can pass real data as buffer too):

```
return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(new byte[4], writable:false));
```